# How can I filter and update a table in Slick with composite key?

Tags: database, scala, slick

I have a table:

```
trait Schema {
    val db: Database

    class CoffeeTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Coffee](tag, "coffees") {
        def from = column[String]("from")
        def kind = column[String]("kind")
        def sold = column[Boolean]("sold")
    }

    protected val coffees = TableQuery[Coffee]
}
```

I want to update entries which are sold. Here is a method I end up with:

```
  def markAsSold(soldCoffees: Seq[Coffee]): Future[Int] = {
    val cmd = coffees
      .filter { coffee =>
        soldCoffees
          .map(sc => coffee.from === sc.from && coffee.kind === sc.kind)
          .reduceLeftOption(_ || _)
          .getOrElse(LiteralColumn(false))
      }
      .map(coffee => coffee.sold)
      .update(true)
    db.db.stream(cmd)
  }
```

While it works for a small `soldCoffee` collection, it badly fails with an input of hundreds of elements:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at slick.ast.TypeUtil$$colon$at$.unapply(Type.scala:325)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcStatementBuilderComponent$QueryBuilder.expr(JdbcStatementBuilderComponent.scala:311)
    at slick.jdbc.H2Profile$QueryBuilder.expr(H2Profile.scala:99)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcStatementBuilderComponent$QueryBuilder.$anonfun$expr$8(JdbcStatementBuilderComponent.scala:381)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcStatementBuilderComponent$QueryBuilder.$anonfun$expr$8$adapted(JdbcStatementBuilderComponent.scala:381)
    at slick.util.SQLBuilder.sep(SQLBuilder.scala:31)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcStatementBuilderComponent$QueryBuilder.expr(JdbcStatementBuilderComponent.scala:381)
    at slick.jdbc.H2Profile$QueryBuilder.expr(H2Profile.scala:99)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcStatementBuilderComponent$QueryBuilder.$anonfun$expr$8(JdbcStatementBuilderComponent.scala:381)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcStatementBuilderComponent$QueryBuilder.$anonfun$expr$8$adapted(JdbcStatementBuilderComponent.scala:381)
    at slick.util.SQLBuilder.sep(SQLBuilder.scala:31)
```

So the question is - is there another way to do such update?

What comes to my mind is using a plain SQL query or introduction of some artificial column holding concatenated values of `from` and `type` columns and filter against it.

Comment: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1606 There's an open issue for that in slick. I think your only option is to go with a native SQL.